# Java - count syllables in a large string

Tags: java, string, arraylist, count

So - I am given two codes to use in order to write a program in java that counts the number of syllables in a string. The codes are:

1. countSyllables(String word) that counts the number of syllables in a single word
2. getTokens(String pattern) that separates words of a string into a list of strings

Now, I am trying to count the number of syllables of a string using the two. The blew is my code which has errors in the last two lines. Would you be able that my logic to get the number of syllables is correct or not? and how could I improve my code to get the result I am looking for?

```
protected int countSyllables1(String doc) 
 {

     //lower all the letters in the string

     String inputString = doc.toLowerCase(); 



     // put all the words of the string into a list of strings     

     List<String> WordTokens = getTokens("[a-zA-Z]+");


      //convert the ArrayList to an Array

      String[] WordTokensArr = new String[WordTokens.size()];
      WordTokensArr = WordTokens.toArray(WordTokensArr);

     //Iterate the array
    for(String s: WordTokensArr) 
       {

        //count the syllables

         int SyllabCount = WordTokenArr.countSyllables(doc);
        }

     return SyllabCount;

  }
```

Here are the helper codes I am using:

```
protected int countSyllables(String word) {
        String input = word.toLowerCase();
        int i = input.length() - 1;
        int syllables = 0;
        // skip all the e's in the end
        while (i >= 0 && input.charAt(i) == 'e') {
            i--;
            syllables = 1;
        }

        boolean preVowel = false;
        while (i >= 0) {
            if (isVowel(input.charAt(i))) {
                if (!preVowel) {
                   syllables++;
                   preVowel = true;
                }
            } else {
                preVowel = false;
            }
            i--;
        }
            return syllables;
        }

        public boolean isVowel(char ch) {
           if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u' || ch == 'y') {
               return true;
           }
           return false;
        }





protected List<String> getTokens(String pattern)
{
    ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
    Pattern tokSplitter = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = tokSplitter.matcher(text);

    while (m.find()) {
        tokens.add(m.group());
    }

    return tokens;
}
```

*UPDATE*

The CountSyllables1 method is modified and working now. It does not detect the syllables correctly but it is definitely giving results.

So here's what I changed:
 1. I shifted the code over to another class which is inherited from the class      that contains CountSyllables and getTokens. I changed the name of the method to getNumSyllables(). 
2. The method does not have an argument (String doc), I also removed the first line where I declared the input string and the toLowercase method as this method has been used in CountSyllables class already.
3. The iteration loop is modified so that variable "result" is declared to help count and return the number of syllables.

```
public int getNumSyllables() 
{

     // put all the words of the string into a list of strings     

     List<String> WordTokens = getTokens("[a-zA-Z]+");


      //convert the ArrayList to an Array

      String[] WordTokensArr = new String[WordTokens.size()];
      WordTokensArr = WordTokens.toArray(WordTokensArr);

    //Iterate the array
      int result = 0;
      for(String s: WordTokensArr) 
      {

          //count the syllables and add to the result sum
          result += countSyllables(s);
      }

      return result;

  }
```

Comment: "errors in the last two lines" - What are those errors?

Comment: You are missing a brace before `public boolean isVowel` for the end of the `countSyllables` method

Comment: Also, last time I checked, "y" was not a vowel

Comment: aeiou and sometimes y

Comment: Laleh H please explain this code `WordTokenArr.countSyllables(doc);` what is the type of the variable `WordTokenArr` ? and which class contains the method `countSyllables`

Comment: @JamesWierzba They're all in the same class as you supposed. well- WordTokenArr is an array of strings holding the words of the text. And, SyllabCount = WordTokenArr.countSyllables(doc) is meat to apply the countSyllables method on each word.

Comment: @LalehH My answer should give you a solution then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the method `countSyllables` ? It appears to be in the current class (correct me if I am wrong), yet you are calling it as a method of `String[]`, which is not right. Also, you need to add up the syllable count of each word and return the sum of them all.

Try to replace your loop with this:

```
//Iterate the array
int result = 0;
for(String s: WordTokensArr) 
{

    //count the syllables and add to the result sum
    result += countSyllables(s);
}

return result;
```

Comment: OP is not calling `countSyllables` as a method of `String[]`. If you look closely, there is  `WordTokensArr`, which is a `String[]` and `WordTokenArr.countSyllables`, which is a method.

Comment: OP should tell us what the definition of `WordTokenArr` is

Comment: I also suspect that `countSyllables` method is in the same class, but she needs to specify

Comment: Aw! Thank you ,my code started working and giving me some outputs using the changes you made to the last bit. I also moved the entire CountSyllables 1 to another class. I can now see some mistakes in finding the correct syllables. Sounds like the CountSyllables method should be manipulated now.

Comment: @LalehH I am happy to help. If it provided an solution to your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

At the end, you iterate over the words to count the syllables:

```
for(String s: WordTokensArr) {
    int SyllabCount = WordTokenArr.countSyllables(doc);
}
return SyllabCount;
```

The variable `SyllabCount` can't be accessed outside of the for-loop. Even if you would declare it before the loop, you would overwrite the value at every word. Instead, add the number of syllables from each word:

```
int SyllabCount = 0; // Start with 0.
for(String s: WordTokensArr) {
    // Add the amount from this word
    SyllabCount = SyllabCount + WordTokenArr.countSyllables(s);
}
return SyllabCount;
```

Answer (score 2):

Some things ive seen:

You don't need to convert the arraylist at all. you can iterate through every list!

```
   //convert the ArrayList to an Array

  String[] WordTokensArr = new String[WordTokens.size()];
  WordTokensArr = WordTokens.toArray(WordTokensArr);
```

vars are usually written starting with lowercase

`int SyllabCount`

"WordTokenArr" is a terrible classname, cause it suggests that this is actually an Array of WordToken rather than a Class.

hope this helps you for the future :)

Comment: It is actually an array! But as you said I shouldn't have converted the ArrayList to the Array in the first place. I am getting there .... ;) Thanks!!